# Capture link ID's with JS then direct to link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event website that spans different sub-domains. In the sub-domains I have links that lead to a club web page. Instead of having many links for the club I want to have one JavaScript file that will capture the specific 'club link' but I'm stuck. My code so far.. thanks. I'd also like them to open in a new tab.

```js
function clubs() {
  $("a#club1").on('click', function() {
    window.location = "http://www.club.com/club1.html", "_blank";
  });
  $("a#club2").on('click', function() {
    window.location = "http://www.club.com/club2.html", "_blank";
  });
  $("a#club3").on('click', function() {
    window.location = "http://www.club.com/club3.html", "_blank";
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class=""><a id="club1" href="javascript:clubs()">club1</a>
  </div>
  <div class=""><a id="club2" href="javascript:clubs()">club2</a>
  </div>
  <div class=""><a id="club3" href="javascript:clubs()">club3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function, `clubs`, which attaches event handlers to the `<a>` tags.  This function should be run only once, or the function part of it discarded so it becomes inline code.  You don't need those inline event handlers either, once you assign the handlers via jquery.  Also, as Hank mentioned, use window.open instead of window.location.

```
<div class="content">
  <div class=""><a id="club1" href="javascript:void(0)">club1</a>
  </div>
  <div class=""><a id="club2" href="javascript:void(0)">club2</a>
  </div>
  <div class=""><a id="club3" href="javascript:void(0)">club3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
      $("a#club1").on('click', function() {
        window.open("http://www.club.com/club1.html", "_blank");
      });
      $("a#club2").on('click', function() {
        window.open("http://www.club.com/club2.html", "_blank");
      });
      $("a#club3").on('click', function() {
        window.open("http://www.club.com/club3.html", "_blank");
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.open("http://www.club.com/club1.html", "_blank")` instead of `window.location`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i got your problem ... You need to do some tricks like below :

**html:**

```
<div class="content">
  <div class=""><a href="#" id="club1">club1</a>
  </div>
  <div class=""><a href="#" id="club2">club2</a>
  </div>
  <div class=""><a href="#" id="club3">club3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a#club1").on('click', function() {
    var win = window.open("http://www.club.com/club1.html", '_blank');
    win.focus();
  });
  $("a#club2").on('click', function() {
    var win = window.open("http://www.club.com/club2.html", '_blank');
    win.focus();
  });
  $("a#club3").on('click', function() {
    var win = window.open("http://www.club.com/club3.html", '_blank');
    win.focus();
  });
});
```

[Click This fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/nadimsajib/ax4zh4cp/)